Автоматическая простановка даты Apps Script
Есть гугл таблица, в которую телеграмм бот вносит определенные данные каждый раз в новую строку! Есть скрипт, который подставляет дату при изменениях в определенном столбце. Все отлично работает когда вводишь данные вручную. Но когда данные вносятся ботом, дата не подставляется! В чем проблема? Вот код:
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("h1");
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  let column = e.range.getColumn();
  let lastrow = e.range.getLastRow();
  let value = e.source.getSheetByName("h1").getRange(lastrow, 2).getValue();
  let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'GMT+3', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  if (column == 2 && value != "") {
    sheet.getRange(lastrow, 4).setValue(date);
  }
}


Проблема в том, что onEdit(e) не реагирует на изменения, вставленные другим кодом. Правильнее будет простановку даты включить в логику кода, отвечающего за телеграмм бот

Уже тоже об этом задумался, буду пробовать!

Решил все с помощью doGet и развертывания скрипта как веб приложение. ТГ бот делает запрос, doGet запускает нужную мне функцию.
function doGet(){
myFunction();
}
function myFunction(){
}

